# How I can make my code to make it not print the first even number?

Tags: python, recursion

How do I make it that if the first number is even it won't print? Also, don't use boolean.

```
def uneven_valley(N):
    if N <= 0:
        return
    if N % 2 == 0:
        print(N)
        uneven_valley(N - 2)
        print(N + 1)
    else:
        print(N)
        uneven_valley(N + 1)
```

I'm getting `10 8 6 4 2 0 1 3 5 7 9`, but I want `8,6,4,2,0,1,3,5,7,9`.

Comment: I can't think of a good way to distinguish the first call from the recursive calls without using a boolean parameter.

Comment: Do you also need to add commas?

Comment: Best way would just be to pass 8 in the first call, instead of 10.

Comment: @Barmar: The way you do it is with a non-recursive wrapper function around the inner recursive function. In this case, it's a terrible idea, because it duplicates a *lot* of code in both inner and outer function, but it's an option if flags are strictly verboten for some reason (and the performance *is* better, because it neither passes nor checks flags for the recursive calls).

Comment: There's also humorous pathological approaches (having the outer wrapper function replace `print` with a function that does nothing when called except delete itself to reexpose the original `print`, so you don't need to duplicate the logic of the inner recursive function at all), but that's ridiculously ugly, not to mention not thread-safe, and I'm not crazy enough to do anything but mention the possibility off-hand. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways to handle this general pattern:

1. Using a flag to distinguish the top-level call from the recursive calls
2. Using an outer wrapper function that behaves slightly differently, before invoking a recursive inner function to do the rest of the work

Here's both approaches:

```
# Option 1: Defaulted boolean
def uneven_valley(N, *, _first_call=True):  # * makes argument keyword only, so it can't be passed by accident
    if N <= 0:
        return
    if N % 2 == 0:
        if not _first_call:
            print(N, end=" ")
        uneven_valley(N - 2, _first_call=False)
        print(N + 1, end=" ")
    else:
        if not _first_call:
            print(N, end=" ")
        uneven_valley(N + 1, _first_call=False)

uneven_valley(10)
print()

# Option 2: Non-recursive wrapper around recursive inner function

# Define a recursive function for all but the outer call layer, marked with leading _ to indicate it's not part of the public API
def _uneven_valley(N):
    if N <= 0:
        return
    if N % 2 == 0:
        print(N, end=" ")
        _uneven_valley(N - 2)
        print(N + 1, end=" ")
    else:
        print(N, end=" ")
        _uneven_valley(N + 1)

# Wrapper function that does the same thing as the inner function, but invokes the inner function for recursion
def uneven_valley(N):
    if N <= 0:
        return
    if N % 2 == 0:
        _uneven_valley(N - 2)
        print(N + 1, end=" ")
    else:
        _uneven_valley(N + 1)

uneven_valley(10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVJNT4NAFLzzKyZtjFLbpMUbkZvxWC/eyRYeuil9S/aDhl@PC5piEQ/14914M8zO7GzV2FfFd207x1NlpWJsYjxQIVxpKcdOqZIEBzkVcEw1cVqLsqTmZrvEYom0kNrYNPO75Fk7CmNgjgUOYk8GQr@4A7HFnpqj0jkUl80SRkFaZIKvLXaEShjTHdVAZJnMPT@AH1lgi/sE67j/7EaTdZoH9AoRkjOGX7Oyn20NWDeVlmw778R5MsMsPKGjdFghOo/3KEpDA/9DCbfYjNTI8/7DUX/ShKPgnLhZh8G7qIdOrUYxtopXmjKnjawJRy2qirTvSDnOMQCS2a8Lx1n3Y998OrISxj9v6Pu86UQFl9/3Bfpeyl/RxNP@Tb6/STHtdXg1Xztv2zc)

For this case, where a lot of the function's logic must be duplicated in the outer function, I'd strongly recommend the boolean flag approach, but if that's off-limits for whatever reason, the wrapper function approach works.

There is a third option if you're forbidden flags, but not things approximating their effect, namely, receiving a defaulted *function* that changes to `print` for recursive calls, with the default being a no-op function:

```
def uneven_valley(N, *, _print_func=lambda *args, **kwargs: None):
    if N <= 0:
        return
    if N % 2 == 0:
        _print_func(N, end=" ")  # Use _print_func when it should be skipped on first call
        uneven_valley(N - 2, _print_func=print)  # Pass plain print for recursive calls
        print(N + 1, end=" ")    # And plain print when it should never be skipped
    else:
        _print_func(N, end=" ")
        uneven_valley(N + 1, _print_func=print)

uneven_valley(10)
```

It's morally equivalent to a boolean flag, but it's avoiding any kind of *check*, which may be enough to satisfy your exercise requirements.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested out your code, adding a call to the function with the value of "10", not only did I get the initial value of "10", the program printed out an additional value of "11" at the end, which I am guessing is not wanted either.

```
def uneven_valley(N):
    if N <= 0:
        return
    if N % 2 == 0:
        print(N)
        uneven_valley(N - 2)
        print(N + 1)
    else:
        print(N)
        uneven_valley(N + 1)

uneven_valley(10)

craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Uneven$ python3 Uneven.py 
10
8
6
4
2
3
5
7
9
11
```

A possible solution I did in refactoring your code, was in effect a "true/false" test; however, instead of passing a Boolean value, the refactored code passes a recursion level to be tested when printing.

```
def uneven_valley(N, lvl):
    if N < 0:
        return
    if N % 2 == 0:
        if (lvl > 0):
            print(N, " ", end="")
        uneven_valley(N - 2, lvl + 1)
        if (lvl > 0):
            print(N + 1, " ", end=" ")
    return

uneven_valley(int(input("Enter an even number: ")), 0)

print("")
```

When running a couple of tests at the terminal, this level check appears to provide the desired effect of not printing the initial even number, but also not printing the final odd number which would be larger than the original even number.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Uneven$ python3 Uneven.py 
Enter an even number: 10
8  6  4  2  0  1   3   5   7   9   
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Uneven$ python3 Uneven.py 
Enter an even number: 12
10  8  6  4  2  0  1   3   5   7   9   11
```

Often times, when utilizing recursive functions, it is helpful to keep track of the recursion level.  Food for thought.